# Add tag HTML sending in string

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have my component like:

```
@Component({
selector:'[seat-for-aecid]',
template:`
<div *ngFor="let html_tag of html_tags" >
<"{{html_tag}}"> </"{{html_tag}}">
</div>
`,
})
export class SeatForAecid{
  html_tags=['div','span','ul'];
}
```

How to make it? Does any way exist to create tag html with a param of array?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve and why ?

Comment: the html_tags is a @Input, I send from other component, but I need create tag_html because the data remote is in string and I want create div or any tag with data remote.

Comment: great question, need some time to think on it, btw you can use `[innerHTML]` too for another use